# dependsOn doesn't work with Resource Name, only resourceId

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, infrastructure-as-code

According to [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/resource-dependency), `dependsOn` value is

> a JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) array of strings, each of which is a resource name or ID.

However, when specifying the fully-qualified name of the resource, I am getting an error saying "The resource is not defined in the template." When I use the `resourceId` function, deployment is successful.

### My code (simplified)

Deploys subscriptions and filters defined in the `subscriptions` parameter. `resourceName` is the Service Bus Namespace name. So `subscriptionNames` copy variable contains an array of Subscription Names in the form `SBNamespace/topic/subscription`.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "resourceName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "subscriptions": {
            "type": "array"
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "apiVersion": "2018-01-01-preview",
        "copy": [
            {
                "name": "subscriptionNames",
                "count": "[length(parameters('subscriptions'))]",
                "input": "[concat(parameters('resourceName'), '/', parameters('subscriptions')[copyIndex('subscriptionNames')].topicName, '/', parameters('subscriptions')[copyIndex('subscriptionNames')].subscriptionName)]"
            }
        ]
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics/subscriptions",
            "apiVersion": "[variables('apiVersion')]",
            "copy": {
                "name": "subscriptions",
                "count": "[length(parameters('subscriptions'))]"
            },
            "name": "[variables('subscriptionNames')[copyIndex()]]",
            "properties": {
                "requiresSession": true,
                "lockDuration": "PT5M"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics/subscriptions/rules",
            "apiVersion": "[variables('apiVersion')]",
            "copy": {
                "name": "subscriptions",
                "count": "[length(parameters('subscriptions'))]"
            },
            "name": "[concat(variables('subscriptionNames')[copyIndex()], '/$Default')]",
            "dependsOn": [ "[variables('subscriptionNames')[copyIndex()]]" ],
            "properties": {
                "filterType": "SqlFilter",
                "sqlFilter": {
                    "sqlExpression": "1=1",
                    "requiresPreprocessing": false
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The same error displays when I try this: `[concat('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics/subscriptions/',variables('subscriptionNames')[copyIndex()])]`.

Template deploys successfully when I replace the `dependsOn` value with `[resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics/subscriptions', parameters('resourceName'), parameters('subscriptions')[copyIndex()].topicName, parameters('subscriptions')[copyIndex()].subscriptionName)]`.

How can I get it to work using just the Resource Name without having to use `resourceId`?

Answer (score 0):

When the dependent resources are not in the current resource template, you need to use `resourceID`. If you are using `resource name` means, the dependent resources must reside in the same template.

Refer MS Doc for the usage of [depends_on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/resource-dependency#dependson) in an arm template.

Here in your case,  you can modify `dependson` as

```bash
"dependsOn": [
    "subscriptionNames"
]
```

as shown in this [article](https://harvestingclouds.com/post/step-by-step-arm-templates-iterating-and-creating-multiple-instances-of-a-resource/) by @20aman.
Instead of adding the provider type and variables, you can simply add a copy loop name before deploying it.

After referring to the sample template for the creation of service bus namespace with the topics and subscriptions from [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-resource-manager-namespace-topic-with-rule), I modified your code with the above changes and was able to deploy it successfully.

```bash
az deployment group create --resource-group xxxx --template-file "xxxpath.json"
```

[image]

[image]

*Note:* If you still prefer not to utilize the `resourceId` function, you can modify the template to add a `copy` loop that obtains the `resource ID` based on the `resource name`. And add this `ID` with a reference variable in the `depends_on` block.

Comment: All resources are in the current template. I don't want to depend on the entire `subscriptionNames` copy, only on a specific subscription. My objective in avoiding `resourceId` function was to avoid unnecessary extra code. Thanks.

Comment: In that case, try to access the copyindex function in this way. `[copyIndex()].subscriptionName` along with the proivider type.

Comment: I believe I am accessing the `copyIndex` function in that way. What do you mean by provider type?

Comment: `Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics/subscriptions/` this is what I meant.

Comment: Get the same error that resource is not defined...

Comment: Can you delete the existing code and try again with the above given changes? @Rachel

Comment: Which changes are you referring to? `dependencies` syntax doesn't work for me (`Template validation failed: Could not find member 'dependencies' on object of type 'TemplateResource'`). As mentioned using fully qualified name fails as well.

Comment: Are you talking about the `dependsOn` block?

Comment: `dependencies` block shown in your screenshot

Comment: After deployment, the output should be in that json way. Before deploying, there is no need to add `dependencies` block in the code.

Comment: Ok got it. So which "above given changes" are you referring to?